# Segmentation Error In Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to write a program for NSDate in ubuntu (as I don't have mac so I am using Ubuntu to run my objective c programs).
While compiling the program I am getting an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
Below is my code

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <objc/objc.h>
   #import <objc/Object.h>

   int main()
   {

   NSAutoreleasePool * pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   NSLog(@"now %@", now);

   NSTimeInterval secondsInAWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
   NSLog(@"secondsInAWeek %@", secondsInAWeek);
   NSDate *lastWeek = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: secondsInAWeek
   sinceDate:now];
   NSLog(@"last week %@", lastWeek);

   NSDate *nextWeek = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: secondsInAWeek
   sinceDate:now];
   NSLog(@"next week %@", nextWeek);

   [pool drain];
   return 0;
   }
```

Please help me to find the error. I am able to get the output for NSDate *now, but after that i am getting the segmentation error.

Ask me if you need any more info regarding the code.

Comment: We don't print NSTimeInterval (double) with placeholder "%@". We use placeholder for double  (since it's in fact a double), like "%f" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Yeah. That was a copy paste mistake. Sorry for that

Comment: As I re-edited my code I am still getting the error as "Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: +[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f81fe2780a0"

Comment: It means that it doesn't know the method. Could be an issue with the "Ubuntu" version of the framework, since it "should exist" on Mac..

Comment: I guess I am able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I am able to get a solution to my answer. I was trying different things and this solution worked but still I don't know how it did.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <objc/objc.h>
    #import <objc/Object.h>

    int main()
    {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"now %@", now);

    NSTimeInterval secondsInAWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    NSLog(@"secondsInAWeek %f", secondsInAWeek);

    NSDate* lastWeek = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-secondsInAWeek sinceDate:now] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"last week %@", lastWeek);

    NSDate *nextWeek = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:secondsInAWeek sinceDate:now] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"next week %@", nextWeek);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
    }
```

I have changed

> NSDate *lastWeek = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: secondsInAWeek
>   sinceDate:now];

with

> NSDate *lastWeek = [[[NSDate alloc]
>   initWithTimeInterval:secondsInAWeek sinceDate:now] autorelease];

Its working fine and giving the desired output. 
I still don't know why and how it worked. :)